# Why close question about what to study?

Tags: discussion, closing

The question [Math for computer science?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155856/math-for-computer-science) was recently closed, without a single person leaving a comment presenting any reason for closure, and this despite my asking for such justification in a comment before the question was closed. So I'll ask it here: why would you vote to close this question?

Comment: Ironically, *this* meta question could be closed as "too localized", since it (only) applies to the four closers of "Math for CS" question!

Comment: Allow me to quote Bender B. Rodriguez in his quote of the English-English dictionary (*The Devil's Hands Are Idle Playthings*):$$\begin{align}&\text{The use of words expressing something other than their literal intention,}\\&\text{Now that is "irony".}\end{align}$$

Comment: Situational irony, my fellow internets addict.

Comment: @Gerry I don't think it is "too localized", so I will gladly cast a reopen vote if a couple others also vote to reopen. Nor do I agree that it was correct to short-circuit the community decision process using a moderator supervote.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't voted to reopen?

Comment: @Bill: _three other users_ voted to close before I did. I don't know how you can call that short-circuiting the community decision process; I would call it speeding it up.

Comment: @Qiaochu Casting a *fourth* binding close vote certainly *does* short-circuit the normal *five* close votes required. Please let the *community* decide such subjective matters *democratically*. And what you call "speeding up", others might call "censorship".

Comment: @BillDubuque Direct democracy isn't the only form of democracy, there's also representative democracy. The moderators are elected democratically, I don't see how a moderator that is using his powers is acting undemocratically.

Comment: @Bill: I notice that you have not reopened the question yourself. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Mad Scientist In my opinion, no *individual* should have the power to decide what material is off-topic here. If that ever became true, I'm sure many would cease participation (as some already have due to such issues).

Comment: @Bill Most moderator decisions can be overriden by the community, even if a moderator closes a question singlehandedly, the community can still disagree and reopen the question. There are enough ways to disagree with moderator decisions (counter-voting, flagging and meta) that I think moderators should not be   afraid to act, they just should be ready to defend their actions and revert them if the community makes a convincing argument.

Comment: @MadScientist Do you encourage moderators to behave in a way that requires constant community correction? The issue of premature superpower closing of contentious subjective threads is a longstanding problem, oft-discussed on meta.

Comment: No, it shouldn't happen often, but it eventually will for any active moderator. I've closed around 300 questions on the sites where I'm a mod, a large part of those unilaterally, and hardly any of those decisions were reversed, and then only after significant changes to the post. Moderators shouldn't be afraid of closing a post if they're convinced it is a bad one, and the community shouldn't be afraid to override a moderator decisions. Such events can often help to improve the site policies, they draw attention to unclear areas.

Comment: @MadScientist Do you have much experience with *general* level math forums? (I ask because I see you have neither asked nor answered any questions on the main site). One of the biggest problems such forums face is deciding scope. Because math has such great breadth and depth, and because it interacts with so many other fields of science, it is a great challenge to decide topicality of posts. The more *democratic* one can make such decisions, the better one can avoid friction in the community.

Comment: @Bill, I generally agree that once the votes are binding one should reserve them for the last vote. However casting the fourth vote as binding means that there is some support to closing the question (especially since no *real* discussion was in the comments). It is no different than someone would have flagged it and it would have been closed.

Comment: @Asaf That there is no meta discussion in the comments could simply mean that folks are following recommendations to not discuss meta matters on the main site.

Comment: @Bill: No, it is usually the case that *some* evidence of a discussion appears. Link to a meta thread; at least two folks discussing it; etc. in particular, I believe that moderators can see deleted comments. So even if there was a discussion that got deleted it would still be visible to moderators.

Comment: @The, I was careful to ask, "why *would* you vote to close this question?" not "why *did* you vote to close this question?" so in fact it applies to anyone who has a reason for voting to close, whether such a vote was cast or not.

Comment: @Isaac, if your question was directed to me, before considering voting to reopen, I wanted to know what objection the community had to the question. Perhaps I could be convinced it's better the question be closed.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, we already know that you are the only one here with sufficient experience to tell everyone else how true democracy works.

Comment: @Phira Please be constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know there are other questions like this on math.SE that are not closed, but to be honest I don't like them either. It seems to me that questions like this are pitched at the wrong level of generality: either they should be more specific to and include more details of the OP's situation (in which case at least it would be easier to agree on an answer) or they should be phrased more generally to apply to situations beyond the OP's (although this comes with its own problems).

I am willing to change my mind, although I'll refrain from reopening the question unilaterally if someone does change my mind so as not to "short-circuit the community decision process."

Comment: If the objection is that there are not enough details of OP's situation, then the solution is to ask OP to provide more details. We do this all the time --- if we closed every question where (say) I wasn't happy with the level of detail provided, about half of the volume of m.se would vanish.

Comment: @Gerry: fair enough. Would you like to begin voting to reopen?

Comment: Not especially, but what the heck, I'll do it.